# Submit Multiple, dynamically created forms but not all

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

So here we go.  I have a page that lists a bunch of unscored sports games.  Here is the query I run to generate the page.

```
<div id="NFL">
    <?php
    foreach ($conn->query("SELECT * FROM game_data WHERE sport='NFL' AND awayscore IS NULL ORDER BY date DESC") as $NFL) {
    echo '<form method="post" action="update_score.php">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            ';
            echo '
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="5%" class="head0">Rotation</th>
                    <th width="45%" class="head1">Team</th>
                    <th width="10%" class="head0">Money Line</th>
                    <th width="10%" class="head1">Spread</th>
                    <th width="10%" class="head0">Over/Under</th>
                    <th width="10%" class="head1">Score</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>';
            echo '
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6">
                    ';
                    $date = date_create($NFL['date']);
                    echo date_format($date, 'l F jS Y \@ g:iA');
                    echo '
                </td>
            </tr>';
            echo '
            <tr>
                <td>'.$NFL['awayrotation'].'</td>
                <td>'.$NFL['awayteam'].'</td>
                <td>'.$NFL['awaymoneyline'].'</td>';
                echo '
                <td>
                    ';
                    if ($NFL['awaymoneyline'] > 0) {
                    $line = $NFL['line'] * -1;
                    echo $line;
                    }
                    elseif ($NFL['awaymoneyline'] < 0) {
                    echo $NFL['line'];
                    }                       ;
                    echo '
                </td>';
                echo '
                <td>'.$NFL['total'].'</td>
                <td><input type="text" required name="awayscore"></input></td>
            </tr>';
            echo '
            <tr>
                <td>'.$NFL['homerotation'].'</td>
                <td>'.$NFL['hometeam'].'</td>
                <td>'.$NFL['homemoneyline'].'</td>';
                echo '
                <td>
                    ';
                    if ($NFL['homemoneyline'] > 0) {
                    $line = $NFL['line'] * -1;
                    echo $line;
                    }
                    elseif ($NFL['homemoneyline'] < 0) {
                    echo $NFL['line'];
                    }                       ;
                    echo '
                </td>';
                echo '
                <td>'.$NFL['total'].'</td>
                <td><input type="text" required name="homescore"></input></td>
            </tr>';
            echo '
            <tr><td colspan="6" align="right"><input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$NFL['id'].'"><span style="padding-right:15px"><input type="submit" value="Submit Score"></span></td></tr>
        </table>
    </form>';
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

This is what I'm looking to do, I would like to have a button to submit multiple forms. Only though if they have placed a value in the score.  Is this possible?  I have read about doing multiple forms based off names but these forms are being created dynamically.  I look forward to your insight.

Comment: It is impossible to submit multiple forms at the same time with traditional form posts to the same target.

Comment: You'd have to use javascript / ajax to do that. But your forms seem very short / simple, can't you put everything in one form and use arrays for the field names like `name="awayscore[<?php echo $NFL['id']; ?>]"`, etc.? Then you can simply loop over the results at the back-end.

Comment: if you want to post multiple forms, it can only be AJAX. So you can have a button and then use javascript to post all the forms with AJAX.

Comment: I knew i'd need to use some form of javascript or ajax.  What happens is when the score is submitted the update_score.php has a bunch of other functions that update a users record if the guessed the game correctly.

Jeroen - yes these forms are very simple, so my question then would be to you how would i simply loop the results in the update_score.php.  This answer seems to probably be my best bet, where its one form and loop.

Answer (score -1):

here try this

I placed a counter that increments by one per SQL result processed This will also be a key we will use later

The counter is now added to the end of the name fields of the inputs (in front of a "-" to be exploded later)

At the bottom of the script is a little code how I would handle the back end information

```
<?php 
        $count = "0";
        echo '<form method="post" action="update_score.php"><table class="table table-bordered">';
        foreach ($conn->query("SELECT * FROM game_data WHERE sport='NFL' AND awayscore IS NULL ORDER BY date DESC") as $NFL) {
            $count = $count+1;
            echo '<thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th width="5%" class="head0">Rotation</th>
                      <th width="45%" class="head1">Team</th>
                      <th width="10%" class="head0">Money Line</th>
                      <th width="10%" class="head1">Spread</th>
                      <th width="10%" class="head0">Over/Under</th>
                <th width="10%" class="head1">Score</th>
                    </tr></thead>';
            echo '<tr><td colspan="6">';
            $date = date_create($NFL['date']);
            echo date_format($date, 'l F jS Y \@ g:iA');
            echo '</td></tr>';      
            echo '<tr><td>'.$NFL['awayrotation'].'</td><td>'.$NFL['awayteam'].'</td><td>'.$NFL['awaymoneyline'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>';
            if ($NFL['awaymoneyline'] > 0) { 
                $line = $NFL['line'] * -1;
                echo $line;
            }
            elseif ($NFL['awaymoneyline'] < 0) {
                echo $NFL['line'];  
            }                       ;
            echo '</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$NFL['total'].'</td><td><input type="text" required name="awayscore-$count"></input></td></tr>';
            echo '<tr><td>'.$NFL['homerotation'].'</td><td>'.$NFL['hometeam'].'</td><td>'.$NFL['homemoneyline'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>';
            if ($NFL['homemoneyline'] > 0) { 
                $line = $NFL['line'] * -1;
                echo $line;
            }
            elseif ($NFL['homemoneyline'] < 0) {
                echo $NFL['line'];  
            }                       ;
            echo '</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$NFL['total'].'</td><td><input type="text" required name="homescore-$count"></input></td></tr>';
            echo '<tr><td colspan="6" align="right"><input type="hidden" name="id-$count" value="'.$NFL['id'].'"><span style="padding-right:15px">';
        }
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="count" value="$count">'
        echo '<input type="submit" value="Submit Score"></span></td></tr></table></form>'



        // back end

        $counter = 0;

        while ($counter++ < $_POST['count'])
        {
            $name = $_POST["name-$counter"];
            $awayscore = $_POST["awayscore-$counter"];
            $homescore = $_POST["homescore-$counter"];
            $id = $_POST["id-$counter"]; // considering you may need to get rid of the count

            $name = explode("-", $name);
            $name = $name[0];

            // ect ect

            // enter in to data base

            //clear all data in strings

        }
    ?>
```

Sorry about that this was due to haters :|

more to the point yes the back end code is for your passer (the code the form is pointed at)

NB: your PHP style is older than what most use now, close to what I use - just check that all tutorials you use give you references to PHP 5.3 and when in doubt go to php.net and check the function calls for version use - syntax and alternate options

Comment: -1 for not bothering to explain WHAT you changed in the OP's original wall of code.

Comment: I see what you are doing with counting.  I'm learning here and this board has helped me learn a lot.  Being negative is not very helpful to anyone who also may ask this question.  Now your Backend code as you put it, does this go into the update_score.php page or no?  I can read what you did but the explination as to what it does so I can see if I'll get the result I need works.  This also account for not wanting the form to post if the score fields are not updated.

Comment: NB: i updated the answer to cover your extra questions

Comment: I've tried multiple times to get this to work and I think I am missing something as it does not seem to trigger the code.  Anyway you can help me out a little more here?